# Question about singleton & inclusion

Tags: set-theory, natural-numbers

I am working on the ZFC construction of $\mathbb{N}$ :

**Axiom of infinity** :

> there exists a set E such that $\varnothing \in \text{E} \,\wedge \forall s \in \text{E}, s\cup \{s\} \in \text{E}.  $ E is said inductive

Let's note $$\mathbb{N}=\bigcap_{x \in \mathcal{P}(\text{E})} \{x | x \text{ is inductive}\}$$

and $$s^+=s\cup\{s\},0=\varnothing$$

Then, it is easy to prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is inductive and the smallest inductive set (for the inclusion relation) 
ie

$\mathbb{N}$ is inductive and $\mathbb{N} \subset {\text{E}}$

From there, induction follows.

I now want to prove the following :

> $\subset$ is a well-order relation on $\mathbb{N}$

I have proven that $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, 0\subset n $ and $n\subset n^+$

I will shortly write the proof of each of these propositions

but I am stuck now, my goal is to prove that $n=0 \vee  \exists m, n=m^+$

Thanks for the help

T.D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go directly for your goal:
Let 
$$N=\{\,x\in\Bbb N\mid x=0\lor \exists m\in \Bbb N, x=m^+\,\}. $$
Then $N$ is inductive. Indeed, clearly $0\in N$.
Assume $n\in N$. We want to show that $n^+\in N$. But that is immediate from $n^+=m^+$ with $m:=n$. As $N$ is an inductive subset of $E$, it is a superset of $\Bbb N$, but is also a subset of $\Bbb N$, hence $N=\Bbb N$.

Comment: my goal is to prove total order, this is a lemma I needed thanks !